# what does the following line of code do?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
var=hashlib.md5(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:16]
```

I was reading a code in python,when I came across the  above code  line.
can anybody explain me what the above code line does ?

Comment: Perhaps you could try executing that bit of code to see?

Comment: dont know pyython but here i go : get a random string, hash it whith md5 en then get a 16 length hex string http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100116165/what-does-hexdigest-and-what-does-it-do\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line creates a random 16 character hex string.

- [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random) produces a random float value in the range [0.0, 1.0).

  ```
  >>> import random
  >>> random.random()
  0.845295579640289
  ```
- [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) produces a string version of that random value.

  ```
  >>> str(0.845295579640289)
  '0.84529557964'
  ```
- [`hashlib.md5()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) creates a [MD5 message digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash object, initialised with the string value.

  ```
  >>> hashlib.md5('0.84529557964')
  <md5 HASH object @ 0x10074c530>
  ```
- The [`hexdigest()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) then produces the hash digest, expressed in hexadecimal. The MD5 algorithm produces a 16 bytes of information, when expressed as in hexadecimal that means 32 characters are produced:

  ```
  >>> hashlib.md5('0.84529557964').hexdigest()
  '5180b52225eac65bee1d6419e28ef397'
  ```
- The `[:16]` slice picks out the first 16 characters. This step is halves the digest to just the first 16 characters out of 32:

  ```
  >>> '5180b52225eac65bee1d6419e28ef397'[:16]
  '5180b52225eac65b'
  ```

All in all, a rather verbose, inefficient and insecure way of producing a random 16 character hex value. I'd use `os.urandom()` instead, encoding to hex:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(8).encode('hex')
'a8cb7b56d476b556'
```

This produces a random 8-byte string value, which when expressed as hex, also produces 16 hex characters, entirely random.

My crypto-fu isn't that great, but I have the impression that the latter form is cryptographically stronger than taking half of a MD5 hash of a string of a floating point psuedo-random value.

Comment: @martijin pieters ,what is md5?

Comment: @shubham Is your Google button broken?

Comment: MD5 is hashing algorithm. @shubham

Comment: @shubham: All I did was show you the documentation here. **Next time** look up the documentation yourself, first.

Answer (score -1):

`md5` is Encryption-Decryption technique which generates 128 bit checksum and expressed in 32 digit Hex number in text format.
so `hashlib.md5(str(random.random())).hexdigest()` will give you this number in a string and
`[:16]` will extract first 16 Digits of that hash and will store in `var`
Read these References for more details .

> [Python Md5](https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html#module-md5)
>
> [Md5 Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)